# Position divs in columns?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs I want side by side that together equal a width of 500px. How should I go about doing this? I was thinking maybe using a `<span>` for this.I don't know where to begin. Thanks

```
<span style="float: right; width:250px; margin-right: 550px;">
  <h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>
  <hr width="100" id="style" />
  <br />
  <form name="ccoptin" target="_blank" method="post">
    <font size="+1" face="LeagueGothic">Email:</font>
    <input name="emailBox" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="Not Available Yet" size="25" />
    <input type="button" class="submitBtn" value="Submit" disabled />
    <br />
    <center>
      <em>Occasional Discounts!</em>
    </center>
  </form>
</span>

<span style="float: left; width: 350px; margin-left: 550px;">
  <h3>OTHER INFO</h3>
  <hr width="100" id="style" />
  <br />
```

Comment: Post some code. Span is not a block, and will not make a 'column' without defining it as a block and it's width/height.

Comment: But you specify div... What have you tried? `.column{width:500px;display:inline-block}` for example, supposing you gave them a class of column

Answer (score 1):

you can use span blocks to do this. I would recommend divs.. But if you must use a span. add to the style `display:block;`

Here is a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tL7Sp/

```
<div style="width:500px;">
<span style="float: left; width:49%;display:block;"> 
<h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>
      <hr width="100" id="style" />
      <br />
      <form name="ccoptin" target="_blank" method="post">
        <font size="+1" face="LeagueGothic">Email:</font>
        <input name="emailBox" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="Not Available Yet" size="25" />
        <input type="button" class="submitBtn" value="Submit" disabled />
        <br />
        <center>
          <em>Occasional Discounts!</em>
        </center>
      </form>
    </span>

<span style="float: right; width: 49%; display:block;">
  <h3>OTHER INFO</h3>
  <hr width="100" id="style" />
  <br />
 </div>
```

Basically to add a div side by side in a width of 500px you would do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="maindiv">
   <div class="divone"></div>
   <div class="divtwo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.maindiv {
   width:500px;
}
.divone, .divtwo {
   width:49%; 
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Always like your explanations and examples.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="main-div">
    <div class="divone">
          <h3 style>NEWSLETTER</h3><hr/>          
          <form class="form">
          Email: 
          <input type="text" name="emailBox" class="textField" placeholder="Not Available Yet">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn">
          </form><br />

    </div>

    <div class="divtwo">
         <h3 style>OTHER INFO</h3><hr/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
          <center>
          <em>Occasional Discounts!</em>
          </center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-div{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.divone,.divtwo{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}
h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
hr{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 54%;
}
.form{
padding-top: 10px;
}
.textField{

}
.submit-btn{
    float: left;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by removing the margin on each span. Also try changing them both to float the same direction. For example:

```
span {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/4d1d5a21245f5ca39be1808060d83802/)

Comment: Those would not be columns, you're missing the height and `display:block;` those are just backgrounded in-line elements. Like a BG on a `A` link.

Comment: I agree a block-level element would be a far better choice, but the user was trying to accomplish this using spans. Also, there was no mention of them needing to have equal height. They most certainly do work as columns, though.